# I am Getting NullPointerException When Converting JSON to HashMap, The Code is Given Below

Tags: java, json, weather, weather-api

I am Really Struggling with this code Trying different ways to Convert JSON to HashMap but still no Progress any help regarding the code would be appreciated.I have tried Searching for the problem but it still Gives me other Exceptions like not a JsonObject and already tried a different lib but Google.gson works best for me please let me Know if you have any fix regarding this...

```
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.net.*;
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.Map;

    import com.google.gson.*;
    import com.google.gson.reflect.*;

    public class Weather {
        private static Map<String, Object> jsonToMap(String str){
            Map<String, Object> map = new Gson().fromJson(
                    str, new TypeToken<HashMap<String, Object>>() {}.getType()
            );
            return map;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args){
            String apiKey = "API not Provided";
            String urlString = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=1174872&APPID=" + apiKey + "&units=metric";
            try{
                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                URL url = new URL(urlString);
                URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    result.append(line);
                }
                reader.close();
                System.out.println("json print: ");
                System.out.println(result);

                Map<String, Object> respMap = jsonToMap(result.toString());
                Map<String, Object> mainMap = jsonToMap(respMap.get("main").toString());
                Map<String, Object> windMap = jsonToMap(respMap.get("wind").toString());

                System.out.println("Current Temperature: " + mainMap.get("temp"));
                System.out.println("Current Humidity: " + mainMap.get("humidity"));
                System.out.println("Current Wind : " + windMap.get("speed"));
                System.out.println("Current Wind Direction : " + windMap.get("deg"));

            }catch(NullPointerException e){
                System.out.println("Null Pointer Exception Occurred!");
            }catch (IOException e)
            {
                System.out.println("Input Output Exception Occurred!");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: May look into this https://github.com/google/gson/issues/1249 . might help you

Comment: I don't really see this as a duplicated of the question marked on the topic. The OP is not asking "what is a NPE", he informed that he's getting a NPE from his code, and tried to adapt to different libs. Maybe point out to him what is causing the NPE is more likely a solution?

Comment: The linked question at the top will give you some tips about how to track down the problem. The first step is to find the line that causes the error.

Comment: @EstevaoSantiago The linked question isn't literally the same. But the answers describe how to find the source of the problem.